# Inline replace comments in files recursively

Tags: find, rename, recursive

I have tried using the `cloc` tool with the `--strip-comments` parameter, which is correctly stripping the comments from all files recursively, with 2 issues:

- it cannot do it "in-place"
- the resulting files are all copied into the directory I run the command from, regardless of where their original location was

The command I have run is

`find . -name '*.php' | xargs cloc --strip-comments=BAK`

How can I get this to do in-place editing of the files or pipe it to something to `mv` the `.BAK` to overwrite the original?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at some other questions led me to a small script which solves the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.php; do
  cloc --strip-comments=BAK --original-dir "${f%.*}.php"
  mv "${f%.*}.php.BAK" "${f%.*}.php"
done
```

This could no doubt be optimised further.

Comment: In `bash`, for `**/*.php` to work, you need `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: `${f%.*}.php` when `$f` comes from the expansion of `**/*.php` is the same as `$f`.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneChazelas, I noticed that when recursion wasn't going deeper than one level - have updated the answer

Comment: using BAK as extension for the _new_ file is a bit misleading. I'd use `stripped` or something like that.

Comment: You may also want to only do the `mv` if `cloc` succeeded (`cloc... && mv...`)

Comment: Note that that `cloc` doesn't seem to work properly, I see it stripping `//xxx` in some `https://xxx` links in HTML parts.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't notice the errors in `cloc`'s output, but out of a few thousand, some files did get incorrectly stripped to the point of syntax errors. Luckily, in this case, I was able to raise exceptions with those files and just revert the few having issues.